# TextBoxes inside listbox in wp7 changing the values entered by user while scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, scroll, textbox, listbox

I have a Listbox

```
            <ListBox Name="lstbox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Name="text" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Width="400"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Here is c# code

```
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            lst.Add("a"+i.ToString());
        }
        lstbox.ItemsSource = lst;
    }
```

I want that user input values in textboxes inside the list box. And the values are display in the textboxes permanently. But When I'm entering a value in a textbox, it is showing the value in other textboxes also. Also when I'm scrolling the list Value entered in text box is lost. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the same weird behavior when i try it too. I suggest you try turning your list into some sort of model that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It seems like you want changes made from the UI (textboxes) reflected ion the collection as well, hence this is a better/cleaner approach IMHO.

Xaml

```
<ListBox Name="lstbox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Width="400"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            customers.Add(new Customer { Name =" Customer " + i });
        }

        lstbox.ItemsSource = customers;
    }
}

public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.name)
            {
                this.name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution. Cheers